# Any experiences on online paid courses (udemy, coursera, edx?

Tags: self-learning, online

I am thinking to start an online course in one of the educational online platforms, e.g. Coursera, Udemy, EDX or other. Does anyone have such an experience? What are some things I have to keep in mind in order to succeed?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

My experience successfully completing a course on Coursera:

- Enjoy learning first. Do incremental learning and track your progress periodically.
- Peer-graded submissions allow you to give and receive feedback from peers; you'll be amazed to learn about other people's points of view and gain insights from a different perspective...
- Mark the deadlines on your calendar so you don't forget about quizzes and assignments.
- Finally you will be able to obtain a verifiable e-certificate...